# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - Issue with the jpql query, not able to retrive the objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

and sorry for botherin you. I am new at working with jpa and hibernate so i have some problems with the typequery. I have a function that recive a string, the name of an "Departamento" and retrives the object ("Carrera") that has that "Departamento" associated with it. In sqldeveloper i have no problem, but in typedquery it has become a bit of a hussle. I am sure that the sintax of my query is wrong, i don´t know how to fix. I would be greatful if someone could help me.

ClientePrueba.java

```
package com.cliente;

import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.entities.Carrera;
import com.entities.Departamento;
import com.entities.Materia;
import com.exception.ServiciosException;
import com.servicios.CarrerasBeanRemote;
import com.servicios.DepartamentosBeanRemote;
import com.servicios.MateriasBeanRemote;


public class ClientePrueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException{
        DepartamentosBeanRemote departamentosBean = (DepartamentosBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/DepartamentosBean!com.servicios.DepartamentosBeanRemote");
        MateriasBeanRemote materiasBean = (MateriasBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/MateriasBean!com.servicios.MateriasBeanRemote");
        CarrerasBeanRemote carrerasBean = (CarrerasBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/CarrerasBean!com.servicios.CarrerasBeanRemote");

        System.out.println("Obtengo todas las carreras del departamento MATEMATICAS");
        List<Carrera> carreras = carrerasBean.obtenerPorDepartamento("MATEMATICAS");
        for (Carrera car : carreras){
            System.out.println(car.getNombre());
        }

    }
}
```

CarrerasBean.java

```
package com.servicios;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import com.entities.Carrera;
import com.entities.Departamento;
import com.entities.Materia;
import com.exception.ServiciosException;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class CarrerasBean
 */
@Stateless
public class CarrerasBean implements CarrerasBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public CarrerasBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<Carrera> obtenerPorDepartamento(String departamento) {
                TypedQuery<Carrera> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Carrera c WHERE c.departamento.nombre = :depto", Carrera.class).setParameter("depto", departamento);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Carrera.java

```
package com.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Carrera
 *
 */
@Entity

public class Carrera implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Carrera", sequenceName="SEQ_ID_CARRERA", allocationSize= 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Carrera")
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=40)
    private String nombre;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private Departamento departamento;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Materia> materias = new ArrayList<>();

    public Carrera() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Departamento getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(Departamento departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public List<Materia> getMaterias() {
        return materias;
    }

    public void setMaterias(List<Materia> materias) {
        this.materias = materias;
    }

}
```

Departamento.java

```
package com.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Entity implementation class for Entity: Departamento
 *
 */
@Entity

public class Departamento implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="Departamento", sequenceName="SEQ_ID_DEPARTAMENTO", allocationSize= 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Departamento")
    private Long id;
    @Column(length=40)
    private String nombre;

    public Departamento() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }



}
```

Comment: createQuery() expects a HQL query. HQL is a different language from SQL. You need to learn it. Not just assume it's the same thing as SQL, because it's not. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I read the document. Another tip you can give me?

Comment: can you give me a hand? i not able to solve it

Comment: You've completely changed your question since you asked it. Now something throws ClassNotFoundException. But you're not saying what, and you're not showing the stack trace of the exception. So I can't help. Anyway, the original question has been closed, and it can't be reopened. So ask **another** question, and provide the necessary information.